# ListView.getLastVisiblePosition() returns -1

Tags: android

I have a custom `ListView` in an `Activity` that is displaying everything as it should. However, I want it to display a selected row in the middle of the list view. To do this I have the following code. It may be worth mentioning that this initial call is in the `onPostExecute()` of an `AsyncTask` called in the `onCreate()` of the `Activity`.

```
ListView lv = (ListView)a.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

int rowsOnScreen =  Math.abs(lv.getLastVisiblePosition() - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());           
int rowToStartOn = myRow - rowsOnScreen / 2;

if(rowToStartOn < 0) rowToStartOn = 0;
if(rowToStartOn > lv.getCount()) rowToStartOn = lv.getCount();      

lv.setSelection(rowToStartOn);
```

These are the following values as the code runs:

- `myRow` = some int (16 for example)
- `lv.getLastVisiblePosition()` = -1
- `lv.getFirstVisiblePosition()` = 0
- `lv.getCount()` = 39 (or some other int)

Now let's say I call these lines, (though a button click) after I am displaying everything to the user

```
int rowsOnScreen =  Math.abs(lv.getLastVisiblePosition() - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());           
int rowToStartOn = leaderBoard.myRank.rank - rowsOnScreen / 2;

if(rowToStartOn < 0) rowToStartOn = 0;
if(rowToStartOn > lv.getCount()) rowToStartOn = lv.getCount();      

lv.setSelection(rowToStartOn);
```

Then the code works, I get a value for `getLastVisiblePosition()` that isn't `-1`. So, what I'm figuring is `getLastVisiblePosition()` hasn't been calculated yet when I first call it right after I build my `ListView`. My main question then is, how can I get that value on the first run through without requiring user interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Post your calculations as a runnable to the back of the ListView's message queue:

```
final ListView lv = (ListView)a.findViewById(R.id.my_layout);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);

lv.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        int rowsOnScreen =  Math.abs(lv.getLastVisiblePosition() - lv.getFirstVisiblePosition());
        int rowToStartOn = myRow - rowsOnScreen / 2;

        if(rowToStartOn < 0) rowToStartOn = 0;
        if(rowToStartOn > lv.getCount()) rowToStartOn = lv.getCount();

        lv.setSelection(rowToStartOn);
    }
});
```